# YouTube подписаться на канал через консоль

Tags: javascript

Я не очень разбираюсь в работе js и пр, но мне нужен кое-какой функционал и я хотел бы спросить об этом у людей, которые понимают в этом.

Суть вопроса: 
Представим себе, что у нас открыта страница любого YT канала, к примеру ImagineDragons, мы залогинены в свой акк и тд, у нас есть красная кнопка ПОДПИСАТЬСЯ. Когда мы на неё нажмём - отправиться какой-то запрос или как это правильно назвать, в общем - можно ли как-то сымитировать нажатие на эту кнопку через консоль (F12)??? 
Я нашёл что-то подобное, но не понял как пользоваться document.getElementById

Так же интересна ситуация, когда мы находимся на каком-то видео, можно ли нажать на лайк/дизлайк через консоль? Вроде айдишник кнопки нужен, он всегда разный или одинаковый?

document.getElementById('subscribe-button').click() 
Вот так не работае

Помогите пожалуйста! 
Спасибо за потраченное время

Answer (score 1):

Подписка:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ytd-subscribe-button-renderer')[1].click()
```

Лайк:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-toggle-button-renderer')[0].click()
```

Дизлайк:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-toggle-button-renderer')[1].click()
```

Колокольчик:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-toggle-button-renderer')[2].click()
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!